# Javascript function only working momentarily

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am making a dynamic graph: http://xenon.colorado.edu/portal/graph/index.php?station=NWOT

Clicking on the x-axis years should zoom the graph in to a specific year, but the setSelectionYear function is only working momentarily. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the href in the links with `javascript:void(0);` it is reloading the page.